# django auth login is not working

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 1.11.4 cannot understand why this code is not working
I am trying to `request.user.is_authenticated()` before and after login but in both cases I get False

if I log in from admin then the same user login

```
user = authenticate(username='myuser',password='mypassword')
if user is not None:
    if user.is_active:
        print("before",request.user.is_authenticated())
        login(request,user)
        print("after",request.user.is_authenticated())
        return HttpResponse("login success")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("account is disabled")
else:
        return HttpResponse("invalid login")
```

Comment: How did you import `login` in your view?

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can implement your own login mechanism however, why not use builtin one specially when it is easier to understand and add?

First import the django.contrib.auth.views module and add a URL route for the login and logout views:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

By default, the `django.contrib.auth.views.login` view will try to render the `registration/login.html` template. So the basic configuration would be creating a folder named `registration` and place a `login.html` template inside, like this:

```
% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

This simple example already validates username and password and authenticate correctly the user. Then you can use [login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required)
 decorator.

Answer (score 0):

i think its because you set a new variable (user)

```
user = authenticate()
```

but inside if you reference to the request.user again

```
print(request.user.is_authenticated())
```

remove the request ... so

```
print(user.is_authenticated())
```